# Is there a way to create an Alexa smart home group and pre-populate it based on discovered devices, programatically?

Tags: python, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

In the process of discovering devices via Alexa, I'd like to create and pre populate groups with devices. The devices being discovered have data pertaining to which room/group they belong to, so it would only seem natural to group these during discovery.

Is this something that's possible? I haven't found anything in their documentation to suggest that it is

Comment: Any update on this problem? I would like to tell Alexa about pre-existing groups associated with the device (endpoint) and also get this group information from Alexa if  that group was created in the Alexa app.

Comment: Any news on this? I found that there is now a 'Device Group Management API' but only for residential partners.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't *tell* Alexa about groups in your discovery response.